# How to force AD FS 3.0 (Windows 2012 R2) to send nbf (not before) in jwt

Tags: claims-based-identity, jwt, adfs3.0

I am trying to receive JWT token from oauth2 endpoint of ADFS in my single page application. I succesfully received *code* from oauth2 endpoint. After ajax POST request i received *access_token* and *refresh_token*. But when i look to access_token i have there only these claims:

```
{
  "aud": "https://localhost/",
  "iss": "http://fs.development.org/adfs/services/trust",
  "iat": 1438015081,
  "exp": 1438018681,
  "email": "Test.User@development.org",
  "role": "Domain Users",
  "unique_name": "Test.User",
  "primarysid": "S-x-x-xx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx",
  "upn": "test.user@development.org",
  "auth_time": "2015-07-27T16:40:01.636Z",
  "authmethod": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "appid": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

As you can see i didn't receive *nbf* claim from AD FS. I cannot find it in configuration of my relying party trust. I tried to set property *NotBeforeSkew* to two minutes and *TokenLifetime* to 60 minutes on my relying party in hope that AD FS start sending nbf claim. But i was wrong, nothing helps in any way.

So my question is this. It is possible to force from my application or from ad fs server to send nbf claim?

Maybe it is just matter of configuration but i wasn't able to deduce from documentation how this claim can be configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I have found to fix this is add a custom claim rule to ADFS. This feels like a bit of a hack, but I simply set 'nbf' to zero and then any consumer will at least not complain about a lack of this property. Although 'nbf' is in fact optional Sharepoint 2013 seems to deem it mandatory when using OAuth which was the original reason in my case that I needed to supply some value. Here is my custom claim rule for anyone struggling with this:

`c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname"]
  => issue(Type = "nbf", Value = "0");`